# How do we access image view of a cell in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView in which I have 1 prototype cell. I created a class called custom cell and made that tableView of that type. I have an imageView on that cell. I dynamically create number of cells.

How do I access the imageView of that cell?

What I have tried is:

```
for i in 0...tableView.numberOfSections-1
        {
            for j in 0...tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(i)-1
            {
                if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: j, inSection: i)) {

                    cells.append(cell)
                }

            }
        }
```

Custom Cell class looks like:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var photo1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var photo2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var photo3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var photo4: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var photo5: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

However, I am unable to access imageView of second cell using

```
cells[2].imageView
```

Can anyone suggest how can I do that?

Comment: Post the code of your UITableViewCell subclass and the code where you try  to dequeue and use the cell, please.

Comment: I think you shouldn't need to do any of that if you use `tableView.visibleCells` instead.

Comment: @PhillipMills It is unclear what do you mean by that? How can I access a particular cell's image view using tableView.visibleCells.

Comment: I mean that your double loop and your `cells` array are not necessary.  As for `imageView`, what do you mean by "unable to access"?  Error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uitableview lazily render views.because of this you should only iterate on visible cells.I advise you to focus on willDisplayCell delegate methods.

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: It uses a dequeuable cell which gets repeated to fill the view not beyond it. Once a cell is out of the view it gets refilled with new contents. Thid gives the impression of say 50 cells while only 7 or so are rendered. To fill views that are going to be rendered use the delegate methods of UITableView

Comment: actually i don't know which purpose you collecting cells.But as i understand from your question title you need make some operation on visible images.So whenever you need to update image on cells first check tableview visible cells if not there you need to wait for recyling/appearing of cell. For this case cellForRowAtIndexPath or willDisplayCell good place of updating subviews of cell.

Comment: To explain it to you, I have 5 cells with one image on each cell. Now I want to change the size of imageView on 3rd cell.